# How to send push notifications to your users

Tags: ios, uiwebview, rss, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How can I send push notifications to my app users?

Let me first start off by saying I'm new to iOS development and I already purchased my dev account and have already built my application that I want to submit to the app store.

Before I submit my application I want to enable push notifications for my users. Basically what I want to do is this: I have a `RSS` news feed that I post every time I have an update for the company... Once I post on the `RSS` feed it's sent to my site homepage and can be read there and is also sent to my iPhone application homepage with a `UIWebView` connected to view the posts on a dedicated site made for the application.

What I want to do is every time I post on the `RSS` feed to have it send a notification to my users with the title of the post being the notification and when they open it, it takes them to the webpage of the post in a `UIWebView`. If this isn't possible to connect notifications to a `RSS` feed then that's fine with me. I can manually send them to the users each time I post.
How do I do this?

Comment: Read this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960

Answer (score 0):

The Push notification are sent by server. there is format which is to be followed and it has to be sent to apple servers. After apple servers receive request for push, it sends the push to users.
For making push you have to set certificates in developers account. 
If you want detailed tutorial then refer
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960